# How to store my li class ("active") when page reloaded other than Cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, c#-4.0

In my menu tab li elements are going to be "active" onclick of the element.

On refreshing the page ..I am storing the value in cookie $.cookie("li", this.id); - which is fine.

But when my loading the website either from local host or in any environment this cookie value stored provoking wrong menu...

which means On loading the website, the cookie sends the old value and makes the other menu in active mode but whereas I am in different menu.

How to get on this one in different way .?

```
        //li Elements

       <li id="Projectsnavtab">
       <li id="Homenavtab">
       <li id="AboutUsnavtab">
       <li id="ContactUsnavtab">


       // Jquery Onclick function 
       var navTopList = $(".siteNav > ul > li").
       $(navTopList).on('click', function () {
       $(navTopList).removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');           
       $.cookie("li", this.id); - Assigning to Cookie
});

      // Getting the value from cookie when page loaded
         var li = $.cookie("li");
         if (li) $("#" + li).addClass("active");
```

Comment: `navTopList` what is it?

Comment: Try localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/wMN7G/200/

Comment: @Jai edited the question its navTopList = $(".siteNav > ul > li"),

Comment: write and read cookie "li" in this page,remove cookie "li" on other page,or you can use onunload event to remove cookie,but diffrent between browsers

Comment: Are you redirecting to another page when clicking the `li`?  Could be that creating the cookie is not happening because the page has already navigated away.  You could add something to the query string to override the cookie or navigate after setting the cookie (depending on whether it's async)

Answer (score 1):

You can use localstorage of Html5.

```
localstorage.setItem('id', 'linkid');
```

you can read it as

```
var linkId = localstorage.getItem('linkid');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can resolve it use url hash(#xxx)
when click a li,give it a diffrent hash, #1,#2,#3...,and you can get the hash by js,then make the li to active.
when refresh the page,it will not lose hash,so you can get the same hash.
when you redirect this page from other page,it will not with hash,so you can set a default li to active

by the way,i think localStorage can not resolve this.it just change where can you find the data,it not change the logic.